# Как с помощью Jquery нажать элемент при нажатии элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.

Есть страница каталога. Там есть картинка-ссылка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она ведёт сюда, на главную.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На заголовке "Наша продукция" стоит якорь. Здесь есть табы(закладки).

Задача: нужно чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с первого скрина был не просто переход на главную, а ещё открывался второй таб(тот, что называется "Авиационные компоненты").

Попробовал вот это:

```
$(".aviation-img-cont").click(function(){
      $("#tab_l2").click();
  });
```

Не работает, хотя если просто алертнуть, то срабатывает.
Таб, в данном случае, это label. Может, в этом дело.

Comment: Это разные страницы и у них разный контекст JS. Нельзя на прошлой странице заранее JS'ом вызвать действие не будущей странице (если конечно вы не балуетесь с урлами через history). Передавайте по ссылке якорь, а на целевой странице проверяйте его наличие и открывайте нужную вкладку.

Comment: Кажется, то что надо. Можно примерный код?

Comment: в ссылке на первой странице добавляешь якорь `href="/foo#bar"`, на второй странице проверяешь его и выполняешь действия `$(function(){ if (location.href заканчивается на '#bar') { $el.click(); } })`